# Are there consequences to writing to an unopened stream?

Tags: c++, stl

If I have this:

```
std::ofstream empty;

for(int i = 0; i < 99999; ++i)
{
   empty << "Nothing..." << std::endl;
}
```

Will this ever cause an out of memory exception or any other problems since the stream is getting data pushed in but it is not going anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I think this was asked as if it was done unintentionally perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the file stream is default-constructed, the 6 pointers to the internal buffer are initialized to `nullptr`. Any I/O attempted on the stream will fail because there is no available memory, and `ios_base::badbit` and `ios_base::failbit` will be set in the stream state.

> Will this ever cause an out of memory exception or any other problems since the stream is getting data pushed in but it is not going anywhere?

The stream is allowed to throw `std::bad_alloc` in this case.

Comment: IOStreams can totally throw `std::bad_alloc`, but not with this code

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, I remember I read that somewhere. Let me change that.

Comment: @KerrekSB There are 6 pointers to internal character sequence located in the `std::streambuf` of the file stream. 3 for the *put* area, and 3 for the *get* area.

Comment: I see. Or rather, there are six pointer-valued accessor functions :-)

Comment: @Milo Stream I/O operators do not throw by default. It might be the case that `std::bad_alloc` is thrown by the input/output operation which is caught by the stream and represented in the stream state as `badbit`.

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong. No data is "getting pushed" anywhere. If the stream is not opened, all output operations on it will fail, as you can easily tell yourself:

```
assert(!(empty << "foo"));
```

Comment: The stream is `good()` *before* the output is made. It only fails when the insertion is attempted.

Comment: @0x499602D2: You're right, I confused this with failing to open a file, `std::ofstream empty("/x/y/z");`

Answer (score 0):

If the stream is not open, it should be treated as `NULL`.  So, the data being sent to the stream should be lost.

Comment: Does "treated as `NULL`" actually mean anything?

Comment: There is a `NULL` stream in Unix, available as `/dev/null`.  If you direct anything to this stream, it is lost.